# CoreData FetchRequest Increases Compile Time from 3 Seconds to 115 Seconds (Swift 5 with Xcode 14.0 for iOS 16.0). [Edit: Too Many sortDescriptors.]

Tags: ios, core-data, swift5, ios16, xcode14

I'm new to iOS development.  If I include the lines

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.topic), SortDescriptor(\.id), SortDescriptor(\.tag)]) var facts: FetchedResults<Fact>
```

then the compile time is 115 seconds, but it is only 3 seconds if I comment them out.  If I include only

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
```

it is 10 seconds.  (I’ve included images of “build with timing summary” below.)  Any suggestions to improve this?

[image: Faster Build Summary]
[image: Slower Build Summary]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had too many sortDescriptors.    I changed

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.topic), SortDescriptor(\.id), SortDescriptor(\.tag)]) var facts: FetchedResults<Fact>
```

to

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.topic), SortDescriptor(\.id)]) var facts: FetchedResults<Fact>
```

and compile now takes 8 seconds.

[image: Build with Timing Summary]